# Android Firebase order database nodes server side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This days I'm facing a problem with firebase.

*I'd like to retrive some values with android, in alphabetical order.*

To do this I made a Query in which i use **orderBy("ex.Name")** and **this works fine**.

Now i added some data to the nodes, and ***I'd like to perform the same query but with one more filter***.

With the Firebase api you can use only one **.OrderBy()** and this prevents me to filter data correctly.

So **I thought about ordering them alphabetically server side**. In this way I will be able to retrive them already ordered and then filtering them on another variabile.

Comment: The server-side APIs for the Firebase Database are pretty much the same as the client-side APIs. If you want to order on multiple properties, you'll either have to use a 3rd party service or get creative. See my answer here for some example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderbychild() method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data